# Prevent soft input keyboard from disappearing when display dialog on acitivity

Tags: android

I am trying to show dialog when user touch on edit text. The problem is when I show the dialog, the keyboard is disappear. How to solve this problem? I think this is because when show dialog, the activity loose focus. There is a similar question in SO. [When Dialog is showing, outside edittext in activity not showing the soft keyboard in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458677/when-dialog-is-showing-outside-edittext-in-activity-not-showing-the-soft-keyboa). But that answer does not work for me. I am using custom dialog which extends android Dialog classs.

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I would try this... `dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);`
Before calling `dialog.show();`

Comment: I already tried that.

Comment: Could you try to remove `.clearFlags()` method, and try without it?
P.S. I think I got it... first call `.show()` and then call `.setSoftInputMode()`

Comment: @arcticwhite I have just tried without clearFlags(). Does not work.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?